# Parse JSON from AFNetworking - Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

i build a sample app to read and parse `JSON` and by using `AFNetworking` framework.

I've defined my array as :

```
var mywholeArray : AnyObject!
```

and in `viewDidLoad` to get the `JSON` :

```
let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
manager.GET("http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json", parameters: nil, success: { (operation, responseObject) -> Void in
    println(responseObject)
    self.mywholeArray = responseObject
    self.mytableView.reloadData()
    println("success")
    }, failure: nil)
```

i want to parse the JSON so i can display it in UITableView. i would like to store title in an Array and rating also in another array...etc

```
[{
        "title": "Dawn of the Planet of the Apes",
        "image": "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/1.jpg",
        "rating": 8.3,
        "releaseYear": 2014,
        "genre": ["Action", "Drama", "Sci-Fi"]
    },
    {
        "title": "How to Train Your Dragon",
        "image": "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/15.jpg",
        "rating": 8.2,
        "releaseYear": 2010,
        "genre": ["Animation", "Adventure", "Family"]
    }]
```

Comment: If you use Swift, try these libraries: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire and https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON. They work perfectly. By the way Alamofire and AFNetworking were written by one author.

Comment: Maybe you can use 'NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData', store the json into a dictionary and then save desired the value into an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something like:

```
    let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
manager.GET("http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json", parameters: nil, success: { (operation, responseObject) -> Void in
    let jsonArrays = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: nil) as? NSArray
        var arrayofDesiereValue : [String] = []
        for value  in jsonArrays {
            if let value = value as? NSDictionary {
                arrayofDesieredValue.append(value["desideredkey"] as! String)
            }
        }
    }, failure: nil)
```

Comment: okey one thing, i tried to put the  `data`  as the `responseObject` but it didn't work.

Comment: Try now, unfortunately I don't have the AFNetworking so I can't test it

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire), which is written in Swift and for Swift. Also, take a look at the [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) library, which was created for the purpose of parsing JSON. In fact, SwiftyJSON extended the functionality of Alamofire to make it easier to parse JSON immediately after receiving it from a network request. For this extension, see [Alamofire-SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/Alamofire-SwiftyJSON).

If you are developing in Swift 2.0, you'll want to make sure to use the appropriate branch in each of the repositories above. For example, Alamofire has a `swift-2.0` branch specifically for developing while Swift 2.0 is in beta. Similarly, SwiftyJSON has a branch called `xcode7`.

In addition, since you need to support iOS 7, these libraries are even more suited for your task. According to the README files in each repository,

> **Requirements**
>
> - iOS 7.0+ / Mac OS X 10.9+
> - Xcode 6.3

Comment: i don't need to use any other third party library's, just parse it with swift.

Comment: @AaoIi You can either write your own solution in Swift, which will be fairly complicated. Or you can use a third-party library that has been developed and tested by many people, which will be relatively easy. Think of a third-party library as Swift code that has been written for you. These libraries were practically made for your exact use case.

Comment: Those library requires 8.0 and up, which will not be useful in 7.0 and up! I'm trying to support lower versions of IOS too !

Comment: @AaoIi look at this: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/tree/master#requirements and https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#requirements

Answer (score 1):

`AFNetworking` has a JSON Request Serializer that you can use to parse your JSON within `AFNetworing` request/responses. The way to use it:

```
let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()
manager.requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer()
manager.GET("http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json", parameters: nil, success: { (operation, responseObject) -> Void in
...
// Use `responseObject` as your JSON object.
...
}, failure: nil)
```